# Windows 7 progress bar sometimes turns yellow

Tags: windows-7, progress-bar

The pulsating green progress bar sometimes turns yellow in Windows 7. It happens in multiple apps and programs, but I can't tell the exact conditions under which it occurs.

Does it mean anything or is it a glitch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug/glitch, it is a feature:

Green means in progress

Red means stopped due to error - Needs user intervention

Blue means paused (although never got to one of these)

Yellow for either paused or hanged.

Comment: My users were manually copying/pasting a large file to a flash drive. I would like to automate this process by creating a Windows batch file or powershell script. Is there a way to display the same windows progress bar when executing the script?